# how to override enum value based on the key in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0, typescript1.8, typescript1.5

I have one based enum like `BasedColor` that I would like to use on other enum as AnotherState. If there is anyway to override the value with the same key. so I do not need to duplicate the key code . I guess I can create a new enum and duplicated the key abd assign to another value. but I am wondering if there is a better way to do it in typescript

```
enum BasedColor 
{
    First= 'red',
    Second = 'blue'
}

enum AnotherState
{
    First= 'light red',
    Second = 'light blue'
    Third = 'from another state third keu'
}
```

Comment: Sorry, looking at your tags, what version of TypeScript are you using?

Comment: So you want `AnotherState` to "extend" `BasedColor`, but also add the `'light '` prefix?

Comment: i have 3.8 actually

Comment: no, I want anotherState to replace the value of name of enum from basedColor

Comment: What exactly should the output be? Should it include `Third` or should it just have `First = 'light red', Second = 'light blue'`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```js
enum Colors
{
    First= 'red',
    Second = 'blue'
}

(Colors as any)['First'] = "Dark Red" // <== here

console.log(Colors.First)
```

Comment: what if I have lots of name need to replace value on the enum?

Answer (score 0):

enums in TS are just objects. So, you can assign them to interfaces that they conform to, and you can "extend" one using the spread operator `...`.

```js
// An interface for the keys a State can have
interface StateKeys {
    first: string;
    second: string;
    third?: string;
}

// Our base state, which we'll extend
enum BaseState {
    first = 'blue',
    second = 'red',
    third = 'magenta'
}

// Our custom state
enum AnotherState {
    first = 'light blue',
    second = 'light red'
}
```

Now we can see how extending works:

```js
// For the example, we'll just print the state's values
function doSomething() {
    console.log(currentState.first, currentState.second, currentState.third);
}

// Start with our state as the base state
let currentState: StateKeys = BaseState

doSomething(); // Prints "blue, red, magneta"

// Now we extend our base state with another state.
// Note, keys/values in objects to the right will overwrite ones to the left
currentState = {...BaseState, ...AnotherState};

doSomething(); // Prints "light blue, light red, magenta"

// You could also extend the *current* state instead:
currentState = {...currentState, ...AnotherState};
```

This way you get inherited values but never have to rewrite the underlying enum, which can lead to unexpected behavior since enums are supposed to be constant after definition.

Comment: actually my question is more like how can I avoid to rewrite `// Our custom state
enum AnotherState {
    first = 'light blue',
    second = 'light red'
}` since I already write enumBaseState with name, `first` and `second` already